# how to prevent watchdog messages flooding dmesg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, watchdog

I'm using the watchdog on an ARM system running Ubuntu, watchdog itself works perfectly fine however since I have enabled the watchdog I get so many "watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!" messages in dmesg that basically dmesg has become unusable. Is there any way to disable these watchdog messages or at least redirect them to a different log file ? I cannot find a way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: How are you using the watchdog dev? Presumably you're getting these messages because something is opening and then closing the watchdog dev without using the proper magic (where said magic would stop the watchdog). You generally want to keep the watchdog open (and keep pinging it) if you don't want it going off.

Comment: I am touching the watchdog every X seconds on purposes, this in an embedded system so I need the watchdog to recover a stuck system. The watchdog works fine, I am just trying to prevent those messages from the dmesg log.

Comment: The way to prevent the messages is to keep the watchdog device open. Closing the watchdog device without stopping the watchdog via the magic character/ioctl causes those messages. If you're building your own kernel you can modify it so that it won't emit those messages, but you're not really using the device as expected.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: aha! ...I didn't realize this was causing the messages. Changed it to a write every X seconds and it works without the messages! ..awesome. Thanks ..please re-post as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "watchdog did not stop!" message is caused by closing the watchdog device without stopping the watchdog (via the magic character 'V').

Keeping the device open will prevent this.